# How do I store a cookie (securely) and keep the user logged in when they re-open a browser

Tags: php, html

How do I securely store a user's password in a cookie while still being able to access that password? I've got a cookie that stores the username and sha1 version of the password but when I try to retrieve them I get the (as expected) username and the sha1 version of the password, and not the password itself. thx!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
  </head>
<body>

<form id='my_login' name='my_login' action='<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
 <label for='username'>Username: </label>
 <input id='username' type='text' name='username' value='<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) echo htmlentities($_COOKIE['username']); ?>'/>
 <br/>
 <label for='username'>Password: </label>
 <input id='password' type='password' name='password' value='<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['password'])) echo htmlentities($_COOKIE['password']); ?>'/>
 <br/>
  <label for "set_cookie">Remember Me</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="set_cookie" id="set_cookie" value="1"/>
 <button id='submit' type='submit' name='submit'>login</button>
   </form>

  </body>
  <html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I securely store a user's password in a cookie

Never store the user's password locally. Even when using encryption that is considered secure at the moment, you are opening a huge potential security hole because you are spreading data for a  possible attacker across lots and lots of client machines.

Give the user a long-term cookie with a random session ID instead. Give that session an expiry time far in the future (storing it indefinitely is not a good idea. Many sites limit it to 30 days.) Have that ID log the user in automatically on your server.

Comment: isn't that the same idea as a password? If a hacker gets control of that session ID then they could login, right?

Comment: @user yes - that's the inherent risk of every auto-login mechanism. But the hacker doesn't learn the user's *password* if he steals the session ID

Comment: Also - as Pekka indicates, you should time limit the validity of the session to minimize the time that a compromised session lives. Even if a hacker gets the session cookie, they can only use it until (a) it expires or (b) it is replaced by another, valid user session when the user logs in using their password.  If they get the password they can continue to login as long as that password is valid.

Comment: To add to what @tvanfosson says:  remember to explicitly ask for the password (even when auto-logged in) if the user wants to change something important, like enter a new password or shut down the account. That way, the session cookie is only of limited use to an attacker

Comment: ok. But how does a site like Facebook have my username & password filled in the box when I visit? (I'm assuming, of course, that they are doing it securely)

Comment: @user that's probably not Facebook but your browser's Auto-login feature?

Answer (score 0):

Also when you use php to `setcookie` make sure you add the last param `httponly` to true.

> httponly
>
> When TRUE the cookie will be made accessible only through the HTTP protocol. This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. It has been suggested that this setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers), but that claim is often disputed. Added in PHP 5.2.0. TRUE or FALSE

Source: [PHP setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

This will mitigate the cookie from being able to be hijacked by JavaScript.

If you have the ability you can also set the `secure` flag to send the cookie only through https.